# how to make complex and interactive SVG object using inline SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to include this [embedded-SVG-Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLM5K.png) as an interactive web element inside my web app.

Within this whole svg, these (red)marked overlay-ed objects will  communicate through ajax calling to a separate application,which will decide their state(change of position or color) in runtime.

As a novice in svg, need help to determine how can I build this SVG object, for my specific purpose. Found inline SVG better among others. Any easier handy useful tool idea or online platform to draw this SVG object, would be really a great help.

Answer (score 0):

All elements of an SVG are loaded into the DOM, so you can manipulate a loaded SVG through javascript or you could use a library to help you with that, based on my personal preference, I would recommend looking at something like [SVG.JS](https://svgjs.dev) wich lets you easily build/manipulate svg images through javascript.

Comment: Since you said complex I'm going to throw out the Greensock Animation Platform (GSAP). It's really good for complex animations where alot of things are happening at the same time and control is needed. You can change the playback speed, reverse and so. The only problem is the API is a little big, so it would take some time. My second suggestion would be anime.js which has alot of good little features + some of the timeline capabilities of GSAP